# Load testing numbers don't make sense

Tags: visual-studio-2015, load-testing

After completing a load test I'm having trouble making sense of the numbers reported, specifically the number of *total requests*.

Using MS Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 I've created 2 load tests:

**Load test 1:**

- Load pattern: Constant
- Users: 1
- Run duration: 1 min
- Scenario: A webtest consisting of 1 API GET request only.

Result:
[image]

Based on this it appears to be executing the Get request every 5 seconds. So my assumption for 1000 users would be 1000 times this, so somewhere around 12,000 requests.

**Load test 2:**

- Load pattern: Constant
- Users: 1,000
- Run duration: 1 min
- Scenario: A webtest consisting of 1 API GET request only, same as last Load test.

Result:

[image]

Only 21 total requests, not even double let alone 1000x. I need to scale this even further however I don't trust the results at this stage. I'm not getting any errors and having trouble making sense of the sparse documentation. Could anyone offer any insight?

Comment: You cannot tell much from just two extreme values on such a short duration. Try a minimum of 5 minutes for the duration so everything (test machine and servers) can stabilize better. Also what is the behaviour at 10, 50, 100, 200 and 500 users? At high numbers of users your servers may be holding up requests.

Comment: The point of load testing is to learn how the system being tested behaves under load. Are you able to [edit] the question to add additional information? Load testing with Visual Studio is a topic with little activity on this site so I think you need to add more details to raise interest on this question.